# How to get record name passing object name, record id (dynamically)

Tags: apex

i want to fetch the record name using record id.
below is my dynamic query

SObject record = Database.query('Select CaseNumber From ' + sObjName + ' Where Id = :subOrderId');

Could anyone please let me know how can i extract the CaseNumber alone from the above query.

Comment: SObject's have [getter methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) with which you can return fields. `record.get('CaseNumber')` doesn't work?

Comment: tried without quotes record.get(CaseNumber) so i was getting some errors. Now, its resolved, Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing fields from SObject use [getter methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) like:

```
// with String
record.get('CaseNumber')
```

or

```
// with Schema.sObjectField
record.get(Schema.Case.CaseNumber)
```